# Encoding error attempting to move DataFrame to S3 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, character-encoding

I'm likely doing this the hard way, so I'm very open to suggestions...

The idea is that I'm (trying) to write a pd.DataFrame object to an S3 bucket so I can the COPY it to a Redshift database. This is the important bit that is falling over:

```
import gzip
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket')
key = bucket.new_key('temp.gz')

fp, gzfp = StringIO(), BytesIO()

csvd = df.to_csv(fp, index=False, header=False)

fp.seek(0)

gzipped = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzfp, mode='w')
gzipped.write(bytearray(fp.read(), 'utf-8'))
gzipped.close()

gzfp.seek(0)

key.set_contents_from_file(gzfp)
```

which fails with:

```
----> 1 key.set_contents_from_file(gzfp)

    <snip>

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py in proxy_ssl(self, host, port)
    795             sock = socket.create_connection((self.proxy, int(self.proxy_port)))
    796         boto.log.debug("Proxy connection: CONNECT %s HTTP/1.0\r\n", host)
--> 797         sock.sendall("CONNECT %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % host)
    798         sock.sendall("User-Agent: %s\r\n" % UserAgent)
    799         if self.proxy_user and self.proxy_pass:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm stumped. How is `gzfp` *not* a bytes-like object?!?

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

Stupid me! The comments below are totally correct, thank you so much! Problem fixed by altering the calls to `sendall` in `boto.connection` to `sendall(bytearray('xxx', 'utf-8'))` and all is good now.

Thanks again!

Comment: Isnt the code complaining about sendall? Or at least I am not understanding the line pointing to 797. It does not seem to have anything to do with gzfp.

Comment: You know, I think you're on to something, indicating I've been staring at this for far too long...

Comment: sendall on Python 2.7 expects string but on 3.6 expects bytes. Are you running the code with Python 2.7 or 3.6?

Comment: @Matt Do you require GZ format or CSV is fine ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [ODO Library](http://odo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). (odo internally uses boto for AWS operations) You can install it using

```
$ conda install odo
```

Next set-up your [AWS credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html).

Now you can use odo to transfer your file to S3.

```
from odo import odo
odo(df,'s3://path_to_csv_file.csv')
```

You can convert `pd.Dataframe` in any of following format : [Conversion Types](http://odo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/conversions.png)

Comment: This looks useful, thanks! However, I cannot use it (at least not without some effort) in this particular instance owing to the very restrictive corporate playpen I'm relegated to. Setting up the credentials is the problem. However, I'll keep it in mind for next time as it looks nice and simple!

Comment: Since `ODO` uses `boto` internally, there are multiple ways to set-up credentials. Check if you can use either of this http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials